# define javavascript key as value

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm getting job value from textarea, I want replace all `ENTERs` by `<br>`
For example job value is:

```
1 ENTER
2 ENTER
3

var job  = document.getElementById('job').value;
var myArray = {job: job};
for(key in myArray)
{
var key = myArray[key].replace(new RegExp('\r?\n','g'), '<br>');
}


alert(job);
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

It should be:

```
1<br>2<br>3
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var key = myArray[key].replace(new RegExp('\r\n','g'), '&lt;br&gt;');
```